# PrimeNG - Dropdown - How to customize by adding few fields in ng-template

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to add a form with three or four controls instead of default text box in prime Ng dropdown.

I tried with ng-template pTemplate="header" and also ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem".

With ptemplate="header", it is working fine. however if when i click on any control in the dropdown it is getting closed and not allowing me to type.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, there is really very little code here to help you. My first impression would be that this component Header is not meant to host more fields that way. I would try to extend it why not with content projection, or create a custom component even.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would find useful informations here :

https://itnext.io/using-an-angular-directive-to-extend-a-third-party-component-39f0f46a4e0

This uses Renderer2 from Angular : https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2